# Find cycles in Graph using Union Find Algorithm on Adjacency List

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, graph, union-find

My code detects if a cycle is present in a graph using Union find algorithm with Weighted tree analysis and path compression.

It works and I have included test cases.

```
# check cycles in graph using union find
# weighted tree balancing added


from collections import defaultdict
class graph:

  def __init__(self):

    self.graph = defaultdict(list)
    self.parents = {}
    self.size = {}

  def addnode(self, key1, key2, edge=0):
    if key2 not in self.graph:
      self.graph[key2] = []

    self.graph[key1].append(key2)

  def findcycle(self):


    for key in self.graph:
      self.parents[key] = -1
      self.size[key] = 1


    for vertex in self.graph:
      for neighbour in self.graph[vertex]:
        x_par = self.getparent(vertex)
        y_par = self.getparent(neighbour)
        if x_par == y_par:
          return True
        self.union(x_par, y_par)


  def getparent(self, vertex):

    while self.parents[vertex] != -1:
      vertex = self.parents[vertex]

    return vertex


  def union(self, vertex, neighbour):

    x_par = self.getparent(vertex)
    y_par = self.getparent(neighbour)
    if self.size[x_par] <= self.size[y_par]:
      self.parents[x_par] = y_par
      self.size[y_par] += self.size[x_par]
    else:
      self.parents[y_par] = x_par
      self.size[x_par] += self.size[y_par]

g = graph() 
g.addnode(0, 1)  
g.addnode(2, 3) 
g.addnode(4,2)
g.addnode(4,1)

if g.findcycle(): 
    print ("Graph contains cycle")
else : 
    print ("Graph does not contain cycle ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `addnode(self, key1, key2, edge=0)`

The parameter `edge` is not used.  Either remove it, or use it, but keeping it with a default value and not using it is obfuscation.

`self.graph` is a `defaultdict(list)`, so testing if `key2` is not present, and setting that key’s value to an empty list if it isn’t present, which is the raison d’être for the `defaultdict(list)`, isn’t using that class properly.  You want the key to exist, but don’t want to add any values to it.  Simply use:

```
_ = self.graph[key2]
```

### `findcycle(self)`

This function returns `True` or `None`.  It would be much easier to write documentation for the function if it returned only one “kind” of value.  Add `return False` to the end of the function.

### Test cases

Put your test cases inside a `__name__ == '__main__'` guard.  Then you can `import` this as a module into another file without the tests running, but running this file by itself will still execute the tests.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = graph()
    g.addnode(0, 1)
    # ...
```

### PEP8

Follow the PEP8 standard guidelines.  Put a space after all commas, don’t put a space before the parentheses in function calls.  Use an automatic checker (pylint, pyflakes, ...) to ensure you don’t violate these guidelines.